# Update field on opportuntiy depending on Opportunity Contact Role

Tags: apex, visualforce, trigger, salesforce1-app

There is a field on Opportunity called Opportunity Contact. It is a look up to Contact.

My approach was to create a trigger on Opportunity Contact Role. After Update of Opportunity Contact Role, the trigger needs to update Opportunity Contact field with the value of Contact ID of the Contact for which the Opportunity Contact Role is Primary.

But Trigger on Opportunity contact role is not possible.

Can any body suggest me solution to update above field?

Answer (score 2):

You can try using batch class for this. Get all the records of Opportunity Contact Role with your specified criteria and update the field. You can schedule the class to run at a specified time each day.

Regards!
Ruchi

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar situation for this.  I used the code at the following link as my base, and modified it from there to meet my requirements.

https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F00000008yPpIAI

Here is the code that I have in my system.

```
trigger CopyPrimaryContact on Opportunity (before update) {

// THIS TRIGGER WILL OVERWRITE ANY CONTACT DEFINED IN THE CUSTOM FIELD OPPORTUNITY_CONTACT__C ON THE OPPORTUNITY OBJECT.
// SET THIS FIELD TO READ ONLY OR CHANGE THE FUNCTIONALITY BELOW TO AVIOD DATA BEEING OVERWRITTEN BY MISTAKE...


   List<OpportunityContactRole> contactRoleArray = [select ContactID, isPrimary from OpportunityContactRole where Role != 'Dealer Sales Rep' and OpportunityId IN :Trigger.newMap.keySet() ORDER BY isPrimary DESC, createdDate];

   for (Opportunity o : Trigger.new) {

       // CREATE ARRAY OF ALL CONTACT ROLES ON THIS OPPORTUNITY. THE REASON WHY WE DONT PICK THE PRIMARY CONTACT ROLE ONLY 
       // IS BECAUSE THE PRIMARY FLAG IS NOT SET WHEN LEADS ARE CONVERTED TO OPPORTUNITIES. ONLY WHEN CREATING OPPORTUNITIES
       // MANUALLY FROM THE CONTACT OBJECT THE IS PRIMARY CHECKBOX IS CHECKED...

       if (o.Opportunity_Contact__c == null && contactRoleArray.size() > 0) {

           // IF PRIMARY IS DEFINED THEN THIS WILL BE THE FIRST OBJECT. IF NOT THE FIRST ADDED CONTACT ROLE WILL BE ADDED...
           o.Opportunity_contact__c = contactRoleArray[0].ContactID;

       }
   }
 }
```

I also have a second trigger that will create a new Contact Role if the user enters the name in the lookup field. I wrote this one to allow the user to add the contact role without having to save the record, scroll down to contacts, add the new contact role, save, then re-edit the record to move to the next stage. This trigger lets the user add the contact role during the initial edit or creation.  There is a check to prevent duplicate roles from being created as a result of the first trigger.

```
trigger CreateContactRole on Opportunity (after insert, after update) {

    List<OpportunityContactRole> OppContactRole = new List<OpportunityContactRole>();
    List<OpportunityContactRole> contactRoleArray = [select ContactID, isPrimary from OpportunityContactRole where Role != 'Dealer Sales Rep' and OpportunityId IN :Trigger.newMap.keySet() ORDER BY isPrimary DESC, createdDate];

    for (Opportunity OppNew : Trigger.new) {
        if (contactRoleArray.size() > 0 && OppNew.Opportunity_Contact__c != null && OppNew.Opportunity_Contact__c != contactRoleArray[0].ContactID){

            OpportunityContactRole ocr = new OpportunityContactRole();

            ocr.OpportunityId = OppNew.Id;
            ocr.ContactId = OppNew.Opportunity_Contact__c;
            ocr.Role = 'Department Contact';

            OppContactRole.add(ocr); // For Bulk processing of the Records.
        }else if (contactRoleArray.size() == 0 && OppNew.Opportunity_Contact__c != null){

            OpportunityContactRole ocr = new OpportunityContactRole();

            ocr.OpportunityId = OppNew.Id;
            ocr.ContactId = OppNew.Opportunity_Contact__c;
            ocr.Role = 'Department Contact';

            OppContactRole.add(ocr); // For Bulk processing of the Records.
        }


    } 

    // Inserting the New Contact Role
    insert OppContactRole;
}
```